# Bootstrap 4 DIV NAVBAR Layout full screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need your help wtih seting up layouts. I'm new with FE dev. I've to make layout like on attached picture:

[desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2FMd.gif)

*NAV on picture are NAVBARs Bootstrap components

How to make it right to have navbars and content div stretched to full page height? When I use attribute min-height: 100vh to nav3 I got scrolling bars. I suspect that this attribute gets height of full window and I have to subtract height of nav2. I hope there is a simple soluton for this.

```css
#dashboardContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#dashboardNav {
  height: 84px;
  width: 100%;
}

#rightBar {
  width: 376px;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 175px;
  max-width: 175px;
}
```

```html
<body class="dashboardBody">

  <div id="dashboardContainer">

    <nav id="sidebar">
      <!-- Left expandable sidebar  -->
    </nav>


    <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light p-0 justify-content-end" id="dashboardNav">
        <!-- Top navbar  -->
      </nav>
      <div>
        <div>
          <!-- Content  -->
        </div>

        <nav id="rightBar">
          <!-- Right sidebar  -->
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: I've updated post

Comment: I have added code. Please check it. If any changes please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review my html and css Carefully.

Hope it will help you. :)

Let me know if you have any question.

```css
 #dashboardContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#dashboardNav {
  height: 84px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #4154da;
}

#rightBar {
  width: 376px;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 175px;
  max-width: 175px;
  background: #de3232;
}
nav#rightBar {
  width: 20%;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    background: #dec514;
    max-width: 175px;
}
.body-content {
    height: calc(100vh - 84px);
    width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 80%;
}
.dashboard {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body class="dashboardBody">

    <div id="dashboardContainer">
  
      <nav id="sidebar">
        <!-- Left expandable sidebar  -->
        <h2>sidebar</h2>
      </nav>
  
  
      <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="content">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light p-0 justify-content-end" id="dashboardNav">
            <h2>Top navbar</h2>
        </nav>
        <div class="dashboard">
          <div class="body-content">
            <!-- Content  -->
            <h2>Body content</h2>
          </div>
  
          <nav id="rightBar">
            <!-- Right sidebar  -->
            <h2>Right sidebar</h2>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't use position: absolute. Its just simple bootstrap 4. Please Modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Hope it will help you. If any changes please let me know.

```css
.dashboardContainer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}

.dashboard-content {
  width: 100%;
}

#dashboardNav {
  height: 84px;
  width: 100%;
  background: purple;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dashboard-wrap-content {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% - 84px)
}

.dashboard-left {
  width: 80%;
}

.rightBar {
  width: 20%;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.navbar h4{
  text-align: center;
}
#content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dashboard-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="dashboardBody">

  <div class="dashboardContainer">

    <nav id="sidebar">
      <!-- Left expandable sidebar  -->
      <h4>NAV1</h4>
    </nav>


    <div class="dashboard-content">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light p-0" id="dashboardNav">
        <h4>NAV2</h4>
      </nav>
      <div class="dashboard-wrap-content">
        <div class="dashboard-left">
          <!-- Content  -->
          Content
        </div>

        <nav class="rightBar">
          <!-- Right sidebar  -->
          <h4>NAV3</h4>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: #Attention please: This example is not according to question, this is not fit to screen and body scrollbar is appear.

Comment: Which code is working well and not this is decide by question owner, This is not your job, And also you need to read this article-> https://stackoverflow.com/conduct